# Proof verification and understanding

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, advice

I am using Topology Without Tears by Sydney Morris

I am self studying it.

Theorem

**If  is an infinite set of cardinality ℵ
prove that there are at least ℵ
distinct topologies on it.**

My thoughts on it.(Edited)

Let X be infinite.

P(X)=$2^{\aleph}$

Let A$\in P(X)$ .Define  $T_A$={$\emptyset$,A,X}

$T_A$ is a topology.

Clearly $A\ne B \Rightarrow  T_A\ne T_B$

So C $\in$ P(X), $T_C$= {$\emptyset$,C,X} is a topology

By A1.2.1 A~C
So U={$T_a$ :A$\in $P(X)}is uncountable

And for our bijection

f:X$\mapsto $ P(X)

If A$\ne C \Rightarrow T_A\ne T_C$
Then B$\in $P(X) and $T_B$={$\emptyset$,B,X} is uncountable.

By A1.2.1 A~B and U={$T_A$ :A$\in $P(X)}is uncountable

Any help to make me understand this
stuff a bit easier would be helpful

Left out first theorem on pg 39
cause answers found. I am wondering
if there are other ways to do it
inductively.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve actually constructed $2^\aleph$ distinct topologies on $X$, which is what you actually need: you slightly misquoted the problem. I will note, however, that many of them are homeomorphic to one another: $\langle X,T_A\rangle$ is homeomorphic to $\langle X,T_B\rangle$ if and only if $|A|=|B|$. If $\aleph=\aleph_1$, for instance, you actually have only $\aleph_0$ pairwise non-homeomorphic topologies, far fewer than $2^{\aleph_1}$. (I’ve used $T_A$ for your $T_a$, since there is no necessary connection between $a$ and $A$: they are distinct symbols, and you want the name of the topology to refer to the subset of $X$ used to define it.) However, it appears from his hint that you’ve done what Morris had in mind.

Nevertheless, some of what you’ve said is incorrect.

- $T_A$ is **not** infinite: it has either $2$ or $3$ elements, depending on whether $A\in\{\varnothing,X\}$ or not.
- $U$ is indeed uncountable, since $\aleph$ is infinite, but that isn’t what you need to prove: you need to show that $|U|\ge|X|$.
- No matter what the set $A$ is, there is no bijection from $A$ to $\wp(A)$: it is a general theorem that $|A|<|\wp(A)|$ for all sets $A$. It is also not clear what any such function would have to do with the problem. The relevant bijection is from $\wp(X)$ to $U$ and is given by the map $\varphi(A)=T_A$.

**Added:** You’re really almost done once you define the topologies $T_A$. You could write it up like this, for instance:

> For each $A\in\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing,X\}$ let $T_A=\{\varnothing,A,X\}$; clearly $T_A$ is a topology on $X$ with $3$ open sets. Moreover, if $A,B\in\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing,X\}$, and $A\ne B$, then $T_A\ne T_B$, since $A\in T_A\setminus T_B$. Thus, if $U=\big\{T_A:A\in\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing,X\}\big\}$, the map $\varphi:\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing,X\}\to U:A\mapsto T_A$ is a bijection. Thus, $|U|=|\wp(X)\setminus\{\varnothing,X\}|\overset{(*)}=|\wp(X)|=2^{|X|}=2^\aleph$, where $(*)$ holds because $\wp(X)$ is infinite.

Note that $T_\varnothing=T_X$, so you can’t keep both of them in $U$ if you want $\varphi$ to be injective; I chose simply to delete both of them. You could keep one of them, but then the proof that $T_A\ne T_B$ when $A\ne B$ has to be broken into two cases, since the topology $T_\varnothing$ (or $T_X$) has to be handled separately.

Comment: I remember that identity. |A|<|P(A)| Thanks . I can’t assume homeomorpism.. If a set has 3 elements how is it infinite? I looked all through the appendix

Comment: @Eudoxus: It isn’t infinite; every one of the topologies except $T_\varnothing$ and $T_X$ is a $3$-element set, and those two are $2$-element sets. Why do you think that the topologies $T_A$ should be infinite (especially since Morris even suggested finding $3$-element topologies)?

Comment: The hint he gives.

Comment: @Eudoxus: That hint says nothing about infinite topologies: it suggests finding **finite** topologies, specifically, ones with only $3$ open sets.

Comment: At what point in my proof can I delete statements?  As to |U|$\geq$|X| by A1.2.10 if $\aleph < 2^{\aleph}$ then $2^{\aleph} >$\aleph$ ?  ok I think I will need help for the rest.

Comment: @Eudoxus: You’re greatly overcomplicating things. Give me a few minutes, and I’ll add a corrected version of your idea to my answer.

Comment: @Eudoxus: Okay, see if what I’ve added clarifies matters.

Comment: Decades ago I heard it was an open problem to find a formula F(n) for the number of pair-wise non-homeomorphic topologies on a finite set with n members. Is this still open?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: [It appears to be.](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL9/Benoumhani/benoumhani11.pdf) [PDF]

Comment: You mean when I added the extra cases?. Yah it does,so that is how U becomes infinite @BrianMScott